# Using Scipy curve_fit with piecewise function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I am getting an optimize warning:

```
OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
                 category=OptimizeWarning)
```

when trying to fit my piecewise function to my data using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`. Meaning no fitting is happening. I can easily fit a parabola to my data, and I'm supplying `curve_fit` with what I feel are good initial parameters. Full code sample below. Does anyone know why `curve_fit` might not be getting along with `np.piecewise`? Or am I making a different mistake?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def piecewise_linear(x, x0, y0, k1, k2):
    y = np.piecewise(x, [x < x0, x >= x0],
                     [lambda x:k1*x + y0-k1*x0, lambda x:k2*x + y0-k2*x0])
    return y

def parabola(x, a, b):
    y = a * x**2 + b
    return y

x = np.array([-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3])
y = np.array([9.15, 5.68, 2.32, 0.00, 2.05, 5.29, 8.62])


popt_piecewise, pcov = curve_fit(piecewise_linear, x, y, p0=[0.1, 0.1, -5, 5])
popt_parabola, pcov = curve_fit(parabola, x, y, p0=[1, 1])

new_x = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 61)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, y, 'o', ls='')
ax.plot(new_x, piecewise_linear(new_x, *popt_piecewise))
ax.plot(new_x, parabola(new_x, *popt_parabola))

ax.set_xlim(-4, 4)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 16)
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a problem with types, you have to change the following line, so that the `x` is given as floats:

```
x = np.array([-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]).astype(np.float)
```

otherwise the `piecewise_linear` will might end up casting the types.

Just to be on the safe side you could also make the initial points float here:

```
popt_piecewise, pcov = curve_fit(piecewise_linear, x, y, p0=[0.1, 0.1, -5., 5.])
```

Comment: How ever did you conclude that?

Comment: I tried to evaluate the `piecewise_linear` with the given data points, and it didn't work, so I concluded the problem must be there somewhere. I think it has to do with some strange behaviour of `np.piecewise`.

Comment: I tried something the same and entirely missed that. Very good!

Comment: I'd suggest `x = np.array([-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=np.float)` which immediately tells NumPy to construct an array of floats, instead of constructing an array of integers and then converting the type.

Comment: @zaq yes, that is nicer.

Comment: You could also append a dot in one of the numbers like `x = np.array([-3., -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3])`, that would trigger np to convert it to float.

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, I'll point out that fitting a piecewise linear function does not require `np.piecewise`: any such function can be constructed out of absolute values, using a multiple of `np.abs(x-x0)` for each bend. The following produces a good fit to the data:

```
def pl(x, x0, a, b, c):
    y = a*np.abs(x-x0) + b*x + c
    return y

popt_pl, pcov = curve_fit(pl, x, y, p0=[0, 0, 0, 0])

print(pl(x, *popt_pl))
```

Output is close to original y-values:

```
[ 8.90899998  5.828       2.74700002 -0.33399996  2.03499998  5.32
  8.60500002]
```