# python non-linear regression: choosing of function depended on param

Tags: python, non-linear-regression

I am currently using "scipy.optimize.curve_fit"

In the equation (piecewise) I fit with, "*theta*" is calculated by one of the params ("*D*") first, then the choosing of equations is dependent on "*theta*" (therefore, dependent on "*D*"). However, it seems that scipy input the params as a list or something, so it does not choose the right equation for each "*D*" individually. Instead, it asks me to use "theta.any()" or "theta.all()" which is not what I want.

Is there any module that can do what I want?

Many thanks,

Christopher

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
def MahonOldham(t,D:'m^2/s',c:'mM'):
    n=1
    F=96485     #A s / mol
    pi=3.14
    a=12.5*10**-6           # m
    D*=10**-10
    theta=D*t/a**2
    if theta <=1.281: #HERE!!!
        factor=1/(np.sqrt(pi*theta))+1+np.sqrt(theta/(4*pi))-3*theta/25+(3*theta**(3/2))/226
        I=n*pi*F*c*D*a*factor #nA
    else:
        factor=4/pi+8/np.sqrt(pi**5*theta)+25*theta**(-3/2)/2792-theta**(-5/2)/3880-theta**(-7/2)/4500
        I=n*pi*F*c*D*a*factor #nA
        
    return I*10**9
```

Comment: You can try [lmfit][1]. It provides an interface to express parameters as a function of other parameters. 


  [1]: https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/index.html

Comment: Check also this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41641880/using-scipy-curve-fit-with-piecewise-function?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the module that you want, you just need to adapt to it's API. The function `curve_fit` passes to your function arrays for `D` and `c` rather than single values, so you need to vectorize `MahonOldham` (and, please, rename to `mahon_oldham`, PEP8).

In particular replace `if` statement by [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```py
I = np.where(
    theta <= 1.281, 
    1/(np.sqrt..., # first case
    4/pi+8/np(..., # second case
)
```

Comment: Thank you, Now i have another problem, lol. my equation is like f(t)/(t+dt), where t is the independent var and dt is a param to fit. my dataset included t=0 and dt=0 is also allowed. Therefore when t=dt=0, the result is not finite, and I think that's what raised the error: "ValueError: Residuals are not finite in the initial point." is there anyway to solve this? Thank you!!!

Comment: @sylvanas Not sure, but try to provide initial point that is not t=dt=0.